# I am having a issue in WebSocket connection between client and server

Tags: javascript, c++, websocket, openai-api

Trying to make a Local Webpage were Multiple clients can chat with single Chatgpt bot.

I am running C++ backend implementation through Visual Studio community and webpage from VS Code (Live Server).

This is my log from Chromebrowser

> WebSocket is not open yet. Message not sent

[image]

I think there might be issue with localhost

[image]

Here is my javascript code and c++ code,

```js
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:7000");  

socket.addEventListener('open', (event) => {
    console.log('WebSocket connection opened. Ready state:', socket.readyState);
    sendMessage();
});

socket.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    let chatOutput = document.getElementById('chat-output');
    chatOutput.innerHTML += '<p>' + event.data + '</p>';
});

socket.addEventListener('error', (error) => {
    console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
});

socket.addEventListener('close', (event) => {
    console.log('WebSocket connection closed. Code:', event.code, 'Reason:', event.reason);
});

function sendMessage() {
    let chatInput = document.getElementById('chat-input');
    let message = chatInput.value;

    if (socket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
        console.log('Sending message:', message);
        socket.send(message);
        chatInput.value = '';
    } else {
        console.log('WebSocket is not open yet. Message not sent.');
    }
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>
#include <cpprest/http_listener.h>
#include <cpprest/json.h>
#include <cpprest/uri.h>
#include <mutex> 

using namespace web;
using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::client;
using namespace concurrency::streams;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class ChatSession : public std::enable_shared_from_this<ChatSession> {
public:
    ChatSession(tcp::socket socket) : socket_(std::move(socket)) {}

    void Start() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(clientsMutex_); // Locking before modifying clients
        clients_.push_back(shared_from_this());
        Read();
    }

private:
    void Read() {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_),
            [this, self](const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t length) {
                if (!error) {
                    std::wstring userMessage(data_.begin(), data_.begin() + length);

                    // Call ChatGPT API
                    std::wstring chatGPTResponse = chatWithGPT3(userMessage);

                    // Broadcast the ChatGPT response to all clients
                    Broadcast(chatGPTResponse);

                    Read(); // Continue reading.
                }
                else {
                    // Client disconnected, remove from clients vector.
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(clientsMutex_); // Locking before modifying clients_
                    clients_.erase(std::remove(clients_.begin(), clients_.end(), self), clients_.end());
                }
            });
    }

    void Broadcast(const std::wstring& message) {
        for (auto& client : clients_) {
            if (client != shared_from_this()) {
                std::wstring messageToSend = L"ChatGPT: " + message;
                boost::asio::write(client->socket_, boost::asio::buffer(messageToSend.data(), messageToSend.size()));
            }
        }
    }

    tcp::socket socket_;
    std::array<char, 1024> data_;
    static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ChatSession>> clients_;
    static std::mutex clientsMutex_;

    std::wstring chatWithGPT3(const std::wstring& userMessage) {
        const utility::string_t apiKey = U("Hidding My API Key"); // ChatGPT API Key

        web::http::client::http_client client(U("https://api.openai.com/v1/completions"));
        web::http::http_request request(web::http::methods::POST);

        request.headers().set_content_type(U("application/json"));
        request.headers().add(U("Authorization"), U("Bearer ") + apiKey);


        web::json::value body;
        body[U("model")] = web::json::value::string(U("davinci-002"));          
        body[U("prompt")] = web::json::value::string(userMessage);
        body[U("max_tokens")] = web::json::value(50); // Adjust as needed

        request.set_body(body);

        try {
            web::http::http_response response = client.request(request).get();
            if (response.status_code() == web::http::status_codes::OK) {
                return response.to_string();
            }
            else {
                std::cerr << "ChatGPT API error: " << response.status_code() << std::endl;
                std::cerr << "Response body: " << utility::conversions::to_utf8string(response.to_string()) << std::endl;

                return L"An error occurred while processing your request.";
            }
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e) {
            std::cerr << "Exception in ChatGPT API request: " << e.what() << std::endl;
            return L"An error occurred while processing your request.";
        }
    }
};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ChatSession>> ChatSession::clients_;
std::mutex ChatSession::clientsMutex_;

class ChatServer {
public:
    ChatServer(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, short port)
        : acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)) {
        Accept();
    }

private:
    void Accept() {
        acceptor_.async_accept(
            [this](const boost::system::error_code& error, tcp::socket socket) {
                if (!error) {
                    auto session = std::make_shared<ChatSession>(std::move(socket));
                    session->Start();
                }
                Accept();
            });
    }

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main() {
    try {
        boost::asio::io_context io_context;
        ChatServer server(io_context, 7000); // Port
        io_context.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried turning off my firewall but it made no difference.

I am expecting to be able to send message from webpage to Chatgpt.

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets and TCP sockets are two completely different protocols. Your code on the JS side is trying to communicate via websocket, but the C++ side is just speaking TCP socket. So the websocket tries to connect to  the server, screams websocket to it, and when the server responds in tcp socket, the websocket has no clue whats going on and just sits and waits for the server to say something in websocket but it never does so it just waits forever.

Here's a random library I found for supporting websockets in c++. I don't know if it works. https://docs.websocketpp.org/.

Comment: They're not COMPLETELY different, but websockets (usually?) run over TCP.  So it sees the start of the connection but the handshake will never happen if the server is just a raw TCP socket server.